# MYSQL IN возвращает только первый результат

Tags: mysql

В таблице `news` есть поля:

```
id   | similar 
8675 | 2876, 6750, 8207, 8294, 8629, 8635, 8362
```

Из таблицы `news` мне нужно выбрать данные новостей где `id IN (similar 8675-й новости)`.

Я делаю это так:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE  id IN (SELECT similar FROM news WHERE id = 8675)
```

И мне возвращаются данные только первой `2876` новости.

Хотя если сделать такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE  id IN (2876, 6750, 8207, 8294, 8629, 8635, 8362)
```

То возвращаются данные всех новостей как мне надо.

Почему же в первом запросе возвращается только первая новость, а не все?

Comment: А SELECT similar FROM questions WHERE id = 8675 что возвращает?

Comment: @MAX `2876, 6750, 8207, 8294, 8629, 8635, 8362` (тип у поля VARCHAR 1000)

Comment: Я, конечно, не настаиваю, но если Вы переведете эту таблицу в первую нормальную форму и сделаете 8675 - 2876; 8675 - 6750 <...>, то все получится.

Comment: У вас неверно организована структура базы данных. Почитайте про отношение "Один ко многим" и "Многие ко многим". Сказал бы точнее, но не понятно что есть что в вашем вопросе

Comment: Я не против почитать, просто не понимаю логики. Почему IN не может использовать возвращаемое значение запроса? Результат ведь полностью соответствует - перечисление чисел через запятую.

Comment: @Vlad Первый запрос возвращает строку, а не множество значений

Comment: потому что `in (1,2,3)` и `in ('1,2,3')` - две принципиально разные штуки. А дальше вмешивается тихое неявное приведение типов mysql, при сравнении числа со строкой строка тихо превращается из`'1,2,3'` в `1`

Comment: Сделайте двумя запросами, тогда можно будет передать полученную строчку во второй запрос в IN. :-)

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() поможет